# How could I fix WICD? it's not longer finding networks

Tags: backtrack, wicd

I'm on backtrack5 R2, and I was working fine, until I installed bind9, the problem is recently the WICD is no longer finding networks, but I can still connect to the networks I had, I've tried with `dpkg-reconfigure wicd` and after restart not noticeable change is done, how can I connect new networks or reconfigure again the manager??

When I search networks with `airomon-ng mon0` I can find some but with the WICD not, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like wicd still manages your network interfaces, otherwise you couldn't connect to existing networks.

Try a command line tool to find find WLANs (e.g. run "iw dev wlan0 scan"), if it does find any move your wicd config from .wicd to wicd in your home folder and restart wicd.
If it does not find any it's not wicd's fault ;)

Comment: I've tried that, and still doesn't work, in fact, `iw dev wlan0 scan` find the network I want to connect...

Comment: At least you know that the rest of your system works properly.
Have you tried a live cd utilizing wicd already?

Comment: yes, as I said, it worked fine, until I installed bind9

Comment: no, you didn't say that it worked until you installed bind9...

Comment: oh, that's right, edited!

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling or downgrading bind9 then?

Comment: Yes, I've uninstalled, stoped the service and still nothing...